# How many methods (pros and cons) for a CSS fixed width center layout?

Tags: css, html

I just want some advice for this layout. I am not an experienced CSS user, so the only technique I've come across is the wrap everything into a div, set the width and auto left/right margin it. Is this method futureproof?

Any precautions or tweaking I should do or have knowledge of before I start? (using em for width instead of px?)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there are other methods but the margin:auto method is one of the easiest and it's certainly futureproof. You don't need to look for alternatives really. As for units it's nice to have fluid layouts but if images form a large component of your design it can be tricky to get it right. ems are generally better for fonts than layout since it can often get tricky to line things up without exact pixel values. Since you're new to CSS go with the easiest approach then work your way up to more complex designs.

Comment: I'm not designing any mission critical sites, or anything with significance. Just starting out here and I'll take up your advice, SpliFF :)

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the following articles:

**A List Apart: Fluid Grids**
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/

and **Smashing Magazine: Responsive Web Design**:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

By using a fluid grid based web design and using the responsive web design techniques, you will find that you have a lot more freedom in your design and your users will have more control over how they view your website.

I find using percentages are usually better than using a fixed width pixel base.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'm really new to CSS and these methods seem really complicated. I've bookmarked those articles for future reference though.

Comment: No worries at all stockoverflow. It's definitely something to keep in  mind and will be well worth looking into when your more confident with css. Best of luck =)